# Размер CheckBox, зависящий от текста на нем

Tags: c#, winforms

Хотел бы попросить помощи с размером чекбоксов.
Есть генератор чекбоксов, который размещает их на `flowLayoutPanel`.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= buttons_count; i++)
{
    CheckBox button = new CheckBox();
    button.Name = "btn" + i;
    button.Text = Read.ReadLine();
    button.Click += ButtonOnClick;
    button.Parent = flowLayoutPanel1;
    setButSize(button);
}
```

Я хочу ограничить ширину чекбоксов шириной родителя, а высоту изменять в зависимости от текста. Пробовал `Autosize` - уходит за границы родителя.
Потом пришел к чему-то подобному:

```
void setButSize(Control c)
{
    Size canvas = new Size(c.Parent.Width, c.Parent.Height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(c.Handle);
    SizeF size = g.MeasureString(c.Text, c.Font, canvas, null);
    c.Width = (int)size.Width;
    c.Height = (int)size.Height;
    Console.WriteLine(c.Text);
    Console.WriteLine(canvas);
}
```

Но почему-то получаю вот это: [image: скрин]
Консолью проверил `c.Text`, `c.Font`, `canvas` возвращают верные данные.
Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Вы не учли отступ слева для галочки чекбокса. Текст же занимает не всю площадь по горизонтали. И с учетом округления размеров, я бы по единичке добавил и тому и другому. А вообще ширину можно задать фиксированную. Почему AutoSize не работает - понятия не имею, сколько помню - все работало.

Comment: у однострочных чекбоксов текст смещен вниз, а у многострочных он точно по центру. возможно, особенность выравнивания в зависимости от высоты контрола. может с вертикальным выравниванием текста в контроле поиграться? также aepot правильно упомянул галочку. ее тоже надо учитывать при выставлении ширины (+размер галочки с отступом) и в высоты (не делать меньше высоты галочки) чекбокса

Comment: @АлексейОбухов, а каким образом я могу учесть ширину галочки, можно как-то взять ее в расчет при MeasureString? И еще, не понимаю, как Вы предлагаете использовать выравнивание текста? Ведь если я поменяю его, чтобы однострочные были по центру - уедут многострочные. И все-таки, почему autosize уходит за границу? Если бы он работал, это было бы намного проще.

Comment: предположу, что AutoSize не работает корректно из-за того, что неверно добавляете контролы в FlowLayoutPanel. Вместо: button.Parent = flowLayoutPanel1, нужно делать: flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button). Если с AutoSize не сростется, то учесть размер чекбокса (пикселей 20) можно так: Size canvas = new Size(c.Parent.Width - 20, c.Parent.Height);

Comment: @АлексейОбухов, flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button) не помогло. Autosize все еще уходит за правую  границу вместо переноса. Не понимаю почему так происходит.

Comment: У меня тоже Autosize выходит за границу. Как вариант, при Autosize=true можно делать многострочный текст: checkBox1.Text = "line1\nline2\nline3"; Возвраты каретки можно примерно рассчитать, где ставить.

Comment: @АлексейОбухов а просто задать ширину фиксированно по ширине родителя + AutoSize не получится?

Comment: AutoSize сама не переносит текст (без переносов всегда будет в одну строчку). Свойство Size игнорируется и выставляется автоматически. Можно менять MaximumSize и MinimumSize, они влияют на вычисляемый размер, но текст остается в одну строчку. А вот если AutoSize отключить, то используется значение из Size и текст переносится без возвратов каретки.

Comment: Попробуйте создать кастомные контролы. Так у вас будет больше параметров, которые вы сможете изменить под себя. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SAA5qDoiL4M или https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7Iv6xfjnuw

Answer (score 0):

В общем, для себя определил вот такое решение проблемы

```
        void setButSize(Control c)
    {
        Size canvas = new Size(c.Parent.Width - 30, c.Parent.Height - 10);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(c.Handle);
        SizeF size = g.MeasureString(c.Text, c.Font, canvas);
        c.Width = (int)size.Width + 25;
        c.Height = (int)size.Height + 30;
    }
```

Отрабатывает идеально, тестировал на огромном объеме текста. Если кто-то этим решит  воспользоваться - играйтесь с вычитаемыми параметрами.
[image: Скрин1]
[image: Скрин2 Фулл скрин]

Comment: было бы интересно посмотреть на результат, если не лень отредактируй ответ и добавь скриншот результата

Comment: Классика: интерфейс, приколоченный гвоздями к пикселям. При изменении масштаба всё поедет. / Ну да ладно. Я вот что хотел сказать: ресурсы нужно освобождать. Используйте `using Graphics g ...` - это автоматически диспозит графикс в конце.

Comment: Ещё замечание. `MeasureString` - это метод GDI+, который использовался в первых версиях дотнета и винформс. Потом по умолчанию стал использоваться GDI (без плюса): `TextRenderer.DrawText`. Эти методы выдают слегка отличающиеся результаты, что в итоге может привести к неточной вёрстке. / По правильному, нужно в зависимости от свойства `UseCompatibleTextRendering` вызывать тот или иной метод.

Comment: @Pekor хорошо, доберусь до компа и сделаю скрины

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да вроде ничего не едет, кроме самих кнопок в панели(выравниваются сверху вниз). Спасибо за совет с MeasureString, но не могли бы Вы, если Вас не затруднит, привести пример реализации не «гвоздями к пикселям»?